# WCF CustomBinding and Proxy

Tags: wcf, proxy

How can I add proxy server to my custom binding in WCF?

Comment: I found the solution:
HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsTransport.ProxyAddress = new Uri("proxyaddress");
httpsTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
stsBinding.Elements.Add(httpsTransport);
where stsBinding is our type of CustomBinding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsTransport.ProxyAddress = new Uri("proxyaddress");
httpsTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647; stsBinding.Elements.Add
(httpsTransport);
```

where stsBinding is our type of CustomBinding

Comment: Ok, and what about credentials, that we need to specify? How should I enter my proxuy username and proxy password?